# Surface Mesh Generation Code in CGAL, not compiling

Tags: c++, mesh, cgal, delaunay

I was trying to utilize the surface reconstruction feature of CGAL (taken exactly from [here](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_reconstruction_points_3/Surface_reconstruction_points_3_2poisson_reconstruction_example_8cpp-example.html), yet I keep getting the error:

```
    In file included from /usr/include/CGAL/IO/output_surface_facets_to_polyhedron.h:25:0,
                 from /home/mrsl_student/git/catkin_ws/src/mesh_map/include/mesh_map/CGALDelaunayTriangulation.h:14,
                 from /home/mrsl_student/git/catkin_ws/src/mesh_map/src/CGALDelaunayTriangulation.cpp:3:
/usr/include/CGAL/value_type_traits.h: In instantiation of ‘struct CGAL::value_type_traits<CGAL::Point_with_normal_3<CGAL::Epick> >’:
/usr/include/CGAL/Point_with_normal_3.h:165:1:   required by substitution of ‘template<class Iter> CGAL::Normal_of_point_with_normal_pmap<typename CGAL::Kernel_traits<typename CGAL::value_type_traits<T>::type>::Kernel> CGAL::make_normal_of_point_with_normal_pmap(Iter) [with Iter = CGAL::Point_with_normal_3<CGAL::Epick>]’
/home/mrsl_student/git/catkin_ws/src/mesh_map/src/CGALDelaunayTriangulation.cpp:21:113:   required from here
/usr/include/CGAL/value_type_traits.h:40:56: error: no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<CGAL::Point_with_normal_3<CGAL::Epick> >’
   typedef typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type type;
                                                        ^
/home/mrsl_student/git/catkin_ws/src/mesh_map/src/CGALDelaunayTriangulation.cpp: In static member function ‘static void CGALDelaunay::TriangulateUsingCGAL()’:
/home/mrsl_student/git/catkin_ws/src/mesh_map/src/CGALDelaunayTriangulation.cpp:21:113: error: no matching function for call to ‘make_normal_of_point_with_normal_pmap(std::vector<CGAL::Point_with_normal_3<CGAL::Epick> >::value_type)’
                                              CGAL::make_normal_of_point_with_normal_pmap(PointList::value_type()) );
                                                                                                                 ^
/home/mrsl_student/git/catkin_ws/src/mesh_map/src/CGALDelaunayTriangulation.cpp:21:113: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/include/CGAL/Reconstruction_triangulation_3.h:25:0,
                 from /usr/include/CGAL/Poisson_reconstruction_function.h:35,
                 from /home/mrsl_student/git/catkin_ws/src/mesh_map/include/mesh_map/CGALDelaunayTriangulation.h:15,
                 from /home/mrsl_student/git/catkin_ws/src/mesh_map/src/CGALDelaunayTriangulation.cpp:3:
/usr/include/CGAL/Point_with_normal_3.h:165:1: note: template<class Iter> CGAL::Normal_of_point_with_normal_pmap<typename CGAL::Kernel_traits<typename CGAL::value_type_traits<T>::type>::Kernel> CGAL::make_normal_of_point_with_normal_pmap(Iter)
 make_normal_of_point_with_normal_pmap(Iter)
 ^
/usr/include/CGAL/Point_with_normal_3.h:165:1: note:   substitution of deduced template arguments resulted in errors seen above
/home/mrsl_student/git/catkin_ws/src/mesh_map/src/CGALDelaunayTriangulation.cpp:24:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘CGAL::Poisson_reconstruction_function<CGAL::Epick>::compute_implicit_function()’
     if ( ! function.compute_implicit_function() ) 
                                               ^
/home/mrsl_student/git/catkin_ws/src/mesh_map/src/CGALDelaunayTriangulation.cpp:24:47: note: candidates are:
In file included from /home/mrsl_student/git/catkin_ws/src/mesh_map/include/mesh_map/CGALDelaunayTriangulation.h:15:0,
                 from /home/mrsl_student/git/catkin_ws/src/mesh_map/src/CGALDelaunayTriangulation.cpp:3:
/usr/include/CGAL/Poisson_reconstruction_function.h:366:8: note: template<class SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d, class Visitor> bool CGAL::Poisson_reconstruction_function<Gt>::compute_implicit_function(SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d, Visitor, double, double) [with SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d = SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d; Visitor = Visitor; Gt = CGAL::Epick]
   bool compute_implicit_function(
        ^
/usr/include/CGAL/Poisson_reconstruction_function.h:366:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/mrsl_student/git/catkin_ws/src/mesh_map/src/CGALDelaunayTriangulation.cpp:24:47: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 0 provided
     if ( ! function.compute_implicit_function() ) 
                                               ^
In file included from /home/mrsl_student/git/catkin_ws/src/mesh_map/include/mesh_map/CGALDelaunayTriangulation.h:15:0,
                 from /home/mrsl_student/git/catkin_ws/src/mesh_map/src/CGALDelaunayTriangulation.cpp:3:
/usr/include/CGAL/Poisson_reconstruction_function.h:519:8: note: template<class SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d> bool CGAL::Poisson_reconstruction_function<Gt>::compute_implicit_function(SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d, bool) [with SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d = SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d; Gt = CGAL::Epick]
   bool compute_implicit_function(SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d solver, bool smoother_hole_filling = false)
        ^
/usr/include/CGAL/Poisson_reconstruction_function.h:519:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/mrsl_student/git/catkin_ws/src/mesh_map/src/CGALDelaunayTriangulation.cpp:24:47: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
     if ( ! function.compute_implicit_function() )
```

I have absolutely no idea why this isn't working, and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Code is below:

```
(Header file)
#include <CGAL/trace.h>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/Polyhedron_iostream.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh_default_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/make_surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/Implicit_surface_3.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/output_surface_facets_to_polyhedron.h>
#include <CGAL/Poisson_reconstruction_function.h>
#include <CGAL/Point_with_normal_3.h>
#include <CGAL/property_map.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/read_xyz_points.h>
#include <CGAL/compute_average_spacing.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
// Type
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::FT FT;
typedef Kernel::Point_3 Point;
typedef CGAL::Point_with_normal_3<Kernel> Point_with_normal;
typedef Kernel::Sphere_3 Sphere;
typedef std::vector<Point_with_normal> PointList;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel> Polyhedron;
typedef CGAL::Poisson_reconstruction_function<Kernel> Poisson_reconstruction_function;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh_default_triangulation_3 STr;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh_complex_2_in_triangulation_3<STr> C2t3;
typedef CGAL::Implicit_surface_3<Kernel, Poisson_reconstruction_function> Surface_3;

class CGALDelaunay
{
    public:
        static void TriangulateUsingCGAL();
};
```

CPP File:

```
#include "mesh_map/CGALDelaunayTriangulation.h"

    void CGALDelaunay::TriangulateUsingCGAL()
    {
    // Poisson options
    FT sm_angle = 20.0; // Min triangle angle in degrees.
    FT sm_radius = 30; // Max triangle size w.r.t. point set average spacing.
    FT sm_distance = 0.375; // Surface Approximation error w.r.t. point set average spacing.
    // Reads the point set file in points[].
    // Note: read_xyz_points_and_normals() requires an iterator over points
    // + property maps to access each point's position and normal.
    // The position property map can be omitted here as we use iterators over Point_3 elements.
    PointList points;
    // Creates implicit function from the read points using the default solver.
    // Note: this method requires an iterator over points
    // + property maps to access each point's position and normal.
    // The position property map can be omitted here as we use iterators over Point_3 elements.
    Poisson_reconstruction_function function(points.begin(), points.end(),
                                             CGAL::make_normal_of_point_with_normal_pmap(PointList::value_type()) );
    // Computes the Poisson indicator function f()
    // at each vertex of the triangulation.
    if ( ! function.compute_implicit_function() ) 
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    // Computes average spacing
    FT average_spacing = CGAL::compute_average_spacing(points.begin(), points.end(),
                                                       6 /* knn = 1 ring */);
    // Gets one point inside the implicit surface
    // and computes implicit function bounding sphere radius.
    Point inner_point = function.get_inner_point();
    Sphere bsphere = function.bounding_sphere();
    FT radius = std::sqrt(bsphere.squared_radius());
    // Defines the implicit surface: requires defining a
    // conservative bounding sphere centered at inner point.
    FT sm_sphere_radius = 5.0 * radius;
    FT sm_dichotomy_error = sm_distance*average_spacing/1000.0; // Dichotomy error must be << sm_distance
    Surface_3 surface(function,
                      Sphere(inner_point,sm_sphere_radius*sm_sphere_radius),
                      sm_dichotomy_error/sm_sphere_radius);
    // Defines surface mesh generation criteria
    CGAL::Surface_mesh_default_criteria_3<STr> criteria(sm_angle,  // Min triangle angle (degrees)
                                                        sm_radius*average_spacing,  // Max triangle size
                                                        sm_distance*average_spacing); // Approximation error
    // Generates surface mesh with manifold option
    STr tr; // 3D Delaunay triangulation for surface mesh generation
    C2t3 c2t3(tr); // 2D complex in 3D Delaunay triangulation
    CGAL::make_surface_mesh(c2t3,                                 // reconstructed mesh
                            surface,                              // implicit surface
                            criteria,                             // meshing criteria
                            CGAL::Manifold_with_boundary_tag());  // require manifold mesh
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented [here](http://doc.cgal.org/4.5/Surface_reconstruction_points_3/classCGAL_1_1Poisson__reconstruction__function.html#a5b01f27b151690449f33c9eb421f7c97), the overload of `compute_implicit_function()` that does not need the solver parameter is available if CGAL_EIGEN3_ENABLED is defined. You'll also need to have Eigen installed and available to your compiler.

At the cmake level, this is done by these commands

```
find_package(Eigen3 3.1.0)
  if (EIGEN3_FOUND)
  include( ${EIGEN3_USE_FILE} )
endif()
```

Also you return a value in a function expecting void as return type.